# How to use Lex Regex to check for a double underscore

Tags: c, regex, lex, regular-language

I'm trying to find the correct lex regex for finding a string literal that can consist of digits,characters, and underscore as long there no two or more underscore in a row. ie

`This__Doesn'tw0rk`

`This_W1LL_work`

So far, I tried using

```
{Letters}(({Letters}|{Digit})*)(_?)({Letters}|{Digit}+)
```

but that shouldn't work due the fact it will only have 1 underscore or no underscore. Where it is possible to have more than one underscore as long it not in a row.

```
{Letters}(({Letters}|{Digit}|_?)*)({Letters}|{Digit})+
```

This doesn't work due to the fact it can allow more than 1 underscore in a row. I'm going insane reading this(http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/) over and over and trying to resolve it.

I have tried using the {m,n} as noted on the website, but that didn't quite work out well either.

Any pointers would be nice, I'm trying to figure this one last issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try

```
{Letters}(_?({Letters}|{Digit}))*
```

This is for tokens that begin with a letter, then contain zero or more instances of an optional underscore followed by a letter or a digit. It should match

- `a`
- `abc`
- `a_b_c`
- `aa_bbbb834758_9zz`

There is no way to accept two consecutive underscores since every underscore must be followed by a letter or a digit.

Bonus: you cannot end with an underscore. Add `_?` to the very end if you would like to allow such a thing.

Comment: Why... Does this work. OOO, I didn't need the | for underscore. I understand now. Ugh, I need to really take my time and study regex again. Thank you. Basically, I didn't need to use the | in my 2nd example for underscore.

Comment: Possibly even better: `[[:alpha:]](_?[[:alnum:]])*` Posix character classes are described in the [flex manual](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#index-character-classes-in-patterns-66).